# Is there exist simultaneously dense and not dense orbit in some homeomorphism on $\mathbb T^n$

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I know in homeomorphism on $\mathbb T^1$ that if one orbit is dense then all orbit is dense. But i don't know in higher dimensional. Can any help me to find such exmaple or proof. Any kind of help will appreciate.

Comment: I am curious that why a  homeomorphism on  $\mathbb{T}^1$ satisfies that if one orbit is dense then all orbit is dense.

Comment: You can see the proof of Theorem(4.3.20)(Poincare Classification theorem)  in book of title "A First Course in Dynamics With A Panorama of Recent Developments" by Boris Hasselblatt and Anatole Katok.

Comment: Look up Arnold's cat map (and more generally Anosov diffeomorphisms). The orbit of 0 is 0 (so not dense), but Lebesgue-almost every point has a dense orbit.

Comment: Thanks for the help